# Figma search for component shortcut key

Tags: shortcut

Is there a shortcut key to search for an instance, component or any object in figma?

I couldn't also find a tool in the menus

Answer (score 1):

`Option/Alt` + `2` will show the assets toolbar and focus on the search input.

I found the shortcut in the keyboard shortcut panel. You can open it in a few different ways :

- Click the `?` icon in the bottom-right and select **Keyboard shortcuts**
- Or use the shortcut :

  - Mac: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `?`
  - Windows: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `?`

Source: https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040328653-Use-shortcuts-and-quick-actions

Note that the shortcut to open the Keyboard shortcut panel doesn't work on my keyboard layout (azerty). Figma recognizes that this is an issue, and now has a keyboard layout selection feature (currently in beta): https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/5665442977431